# it-books API doesn't let the user download directly a chosen book

Tags: php, api

I need some help, as I wrote a PHP class which uses this good API:
 http://it-ebooks-api.info and it works great. From my form, you can put an argument like PHP, Jquery, etc. and you'll get the results of all the first 10 found books, and at the end I use a Select to let the user have a look at all the rest of  the results/books.

Now the I notice that only the original API website let you download the books directly. 
I guess they use some JavaScript code together with a session that after some time falls down, to prevent users of  their free API to download directly the book you may need.

If you click on the download link you'll end up on another page with the details of book with a captcha you have to fulfill! 
Once done that, the download finally starts!

Is it possible to avoid that, and have the possibility to download directly the book I need, without landing on the damned page with that annoying captcha?

It's a free API but this behavior is something that goes beyond freedom: you must accept to go to that page, execute the captcha the right way (of course) and only then, thanks 'em or for God's sake, you're allowed to download your chosen book.

This attitude makes me angry, as I don't appreciate such a fake free API, but nonetheless I searched the web thru, but I got nothing better.

I do appreciate some helping hand.

Here's my class, I called it **EbooksSearchDownload**.

```
    <?php
     class EbooksSearchDownload 
     {

     // Error code / description (Note: request success code = 0)
     public $Error;

    // Request query execution time (seconds)
    public $Time; 

    // Array which contains all details of the books
    public $books;

    // The total number of books found 
    public $total;

   // The total number of pages/results (Note: limit = 10 books per page)
   public $pages;


    public function __construct($ebook, $page)
    {
        /**
         * See here for info about this API: http://it-ebooks-api.info/
         * First the book search, this way:          
         * http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/{QUERY}/page/{NUMBER}
         */
        $response = $this->fetch("http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/search/{$ebook}/page/{$page}");

        // decode the JSON into an associative array, setting the option to true
        $data = json_decode($response, true);

        # This will print out the contents of the array in a nice readable format     
        # echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, true) . '</pre>';

        $this->total = $data['Total'];

        /**
         * HOW TO GET THE TOTAL NUMBER OF PAGES:
         *
         * As the API shows only 10 books per page, if I want to know how many pages contain 
         * all books (here the property, $total), I have to pass thru three different steps:
         *
         * 1) I divide the total number of the books by 10: e.g. 141/10 gives 14,1
         *
         * 2) then I use the function intval() to get the integer value stripping the 
         *    the decimal part: e.g. 14
         *
         * 3) then, if there is a remainder from the division, I get it with the modulus
         *    operator % and I add one more page to obtain the number of the total pages:
         *    e.g. here the 1 and in this case, I've got 141 books on 15 pages. 
         */
        $this->pages = intval($data['Total']/10) + ($data['Total']%10 ? 1 : 0);


        // Extract all details about the books
        // Here I use 'Books' as the key to the array to get all info. 
        // 'Books' and 'ID' come from the API above.
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count($data['Books']); $i++ ) 
            {
                /** 
                 * Then the download and other info of the chosen book, this way:
                 * http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/{ID}
                 */
                    $response = $this->fetch("http://it-ebooks-api.info/v1/book/{$data['Books'][$i]['ID']}");
                    $this->books[] = json_decode($response, true);
            }               
        }

    public function fetch($host) 
    {
        if ( function_exists('curl_init') )
            {   
                    $ch = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

                    $response = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
            }
        else if ( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) 
            {
                    $response = file_get_contents($host, 'r');
            }

        return $response;
        }
 }
```

And here is how I use it (I omit the head and body tags):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

require_once 'settings_ebook.php';

require_once 'EbooksSearchDownload.class.php';

echo "
<h1 class='centra sottolineato grassetto rosso'>Cerca un argomento e scarica un ebook</h1>

<form action='ebook.php' method='get' id='ebookForm'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend class='centra'>Inserisci un argomento e cerca un ebook</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for='ebook'>Ebook<abbr title='campo obbligatorio'>*</abbr></label>
                <input type='text' name='ebook' id='ebook' value='" . ( isset($_GET['ebook']) && ! empty($_GET['ebook']) ? strip_tags(trim($_GET['ebook'])) : '' ) . "' class='" . ( isset($_GET['ebook']) && empty($_GET['ebook']) ? 'error' : '' ) . "'  />   
            </li>
        </ol>
    </fieldset>
        <p class='controls'>   
            <input type='submit' value='Invia' />           
        </p> 
</form>";


if ( isset($_GET['ebook']) && ! empty($_GET['ebook']) ) 
    {
        $_GET['page'] = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $eb = new EbooksSearchDownload($_GET['ebook'], $_GET['page']);

        /**
         * Check for the results!
         * 
         */         
        if ( is_array($eb->books) )
            { 
                echo "Totale libri: " . $eb->total . " - Pagina {$_GET['page']} di " . $eb->pages . "<br /><br /><hr class='style-eight'></hr>";
                foreach ( $eb->books as $book )
                    {   
                        // the first 10 books:                      
                        echo '<p>' .                    
                        //  'Error code: ' . $book['Error']  . '<br />' .
                        //  'Request query execution time: ' . $book['Time']  . '<br /></p>' .
                            'Tempo esecuzione della query: ' . $book['Time'] . '<br /></p>' .
                            '<p class="grassetto">' . 'ID ebook: ' . '</p>' .
                            '<p>' . $book['ID'] . '</p>' .

                            '<p class="grassetto rosso sottolineato">' . 'Titolo: ' . '</p>' .
                            '<p class="rosso">' . $book['Title'] . '</p>' . 
                            '<p class="grassetto" >' . 'Sottotitolo: ' . '</p>' .
                            '<p>' . $book['SubTitle'] . '</p>' .
                            '<p class="grassetto">' . 'Descrizione: ' . '</p>' .
                            '<p>' . $book['Description'] . '<br /></p>' .
                            '<p class="grassetto rosso sottolineato">' . 'Autore: ' . '</p>' .
                            '<p class="rosso">' . $book['Author'] . '<br /></p>' .
                            '<p class="grassetto">' . 'ISBN: ' . '</p>' .   
                            '<p>' . $book['ISBN'] . '<br /></p>' .
                            '<p class="grassetto">' . 'Anno: ' . '</p>' .
                            '<p>' . $book['Year'] . '<br /></p>' .
                            '<p class="grassetto">' . 'Pagine: ' . '</p>' .
                            '<p>' . $book['Page'] . '<br /></p>' .
                            '<p class="grassetto rosso sottolineato">' . 'Casa Editrice: ' . '</p>' .
                            '<p class="rosso">' . $book['Publisher'] . '<br /></p>' .
                            '<p><img src="' . $book['Image'] . '" alt="" />' . '</p>' .
                            '<p><a href="' . $book['Download'] . '" target="_blank">' . 'scarica' . '</a>' . '<br /></p><hr class="style-eight"></hr>';

                    }

                echo "
                    <form action='ebook.php' method='get'>
                            Pagina
                                <select name='page' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";

                        for ( $i = 1; $i <= $eb->pages; $i++ )
                            {
                                echo "
                                    <option value='{$i}'" . ( $i == $_GET['page'] ? " selected='selected'" : "" ) . ">{$i}</option>";
                            }

                        echo "
                                </select>
                            <input type='hidden' name='ebook' value='{$_GET['ebook']}' />
                    </form>";

                        // show a message for the correct data
                        $info_message = '<p class="info">' . $ebook_existing . '</p>';
             }
    }

   /* ERRORS TO BE PRINTED ON THE SCREEN */

  // if not all required fields have been filled
  if (  isset($_GET['ebook']) && empty($_GET['ebook']) )
   $info_message = '<p class="error">' . $error_missing_field . '</p>';

  // if the ebook doesn't exist
   else if ( isset($_GET['ebook']) && ! empty($_GET['ebook']) && !    is_array($eb->books) )
    $info_message = '<p class="error">' . $ebook_unexisting . '</p>';



   // Show both a confirm message and an error message
   if ( isset( $info_message) && strlen($info_message) ) 
     echo $info_message;        
?>
```

Here's my website (in Italian) that uses the API as described above. [if you wanna have a look:](http://newbielinux.altervista.org/ebook.php)

Thanks.

Comment: Well, that should be clearly explained in the documentation, since you are using an official API. If not, then you should consult them. How should we know what they implement on their side?

Comment: If they would allow direct download, their site would become a potential money maker to other people for free,so why would they allow it.

Comment: @arkascha I guessed somebody could help me in doing some reverse engineering studying their page, but maybe the point is exactly what Mihai has just said: they don't want their "free" API" become a money maker for other people, who could download this way (with my class for instance) as many ebooks as they want, in pdf format, of course.

Comment: Are you sure the site you are using isn't highly illegal ?

Comment: They should be more honest in letting webmasters using the API: they could say: use it , let your users have a look of the books they may need but that's all!. The download link will then land you on a page of ours, with a captcha too! Maybe this way they earn some money, I can presume now: or do they have no interest at all, in acting like that?

Comment: Even if you could reverse engineer that (which I doubt, since you can only see the client side), I doubt that is a good idea. You should keep in mind that reverse engineering APIs and protocols has been declared illegal in most parts of the world some 5 to 10 years ago due to the huge pressure of old fashioned, closed source based companies. You should think twice about offering such a service because of that. In general one should only offer content one owns or is allowed to. Everything else might be called stealing.

Comment: I'm using an API of them: that's all. No direct download is permitted thru my website. It's all up to them to let users download the ebooks. My hands are tied! I just use what they legally want a webmaster can do.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a bug it's a feature.

Presumably for security reasons, to protect against (D)DOS attacks and/or maybe for licensing reasons to prevent mass downloads.

But in case you are feeling lucky: The book with the download URL

```
http://filepi.com/i/qqkNNW2
```

can be actually downloaded (after entering the captcha) at

```
http://cdn2.filepi.com/g/qqkNNW2/1446376978/4a79bb1807795fdec1313e97bfd43d1b
```

which follows the pattern:

```
http://cdn2.filepi.com/[g instead of i]/[book id]/[current timestamp]/[md5 hash]
```

If the hash is generated over something simple that puzzle might be crackable.
So on your idea reverse engineering this: good luck!

Comment: @S. Dochow thank you, but as you and others here say, it's much better to let this thing disappear, to avoid legal problems: I just use their API to give my users a service, but as things go this way, it's better to let them take the responsibility for the download issue. Bye.

Comment: To give the issue an end, just read this: [basic link](http://filepi.com/dmca). That's how I resolve it: giving anybody the chance to have a look at the book/s they need, but then it's up to you deciding what to do following the download link to the page that this API takes you. It's a little sad, but I see no other solution possible for me as a webmaster using this API not to be accused of copyright infringement.